# Unrecognized authentication type - Logstash

Tags: email, smtp, logstash

I am getting the below error while sending a mail Via Logstash email plugin ,

```
←[31mSomething happen while delivering an email {:exception=>#<Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type
```

Below is my Logstash Confifuration for email plugin :

```
email {
    from => "mymail@domain.com"
    options => [ "smtpIporHost", "my ip",
         "port", "25",
         "userName", "mymail@domain.com",
         "password", "password"
       ]
  via => "smtp" # or pop or sendmail
  subject => "Alert from Logstash"
   body => "Here is the event line %{@message}"
   htmlbody => "<h2></h2><br/><br/><h3>Full Event</h3><br/><br/><div align='center'>%{@message}</div>"
}
```

But when I use JAVA client (a java program) to send a mail, I am able to send a mail but cannot reciprocate with Logstash.

Am I missng any configuration ? to avoid the above error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly email plugin version you are using in your logstash, but you should add:

```
authentication => "login"
```